# Is there a way to performSegue from a NSObject Class

Tags: objective-c, segue

I am curious if there is a way to call a segue from a NSObject Class ?

I am calling a method in a UIViewController class from an NSObject Class. I am calling the method just fine and using NSLog so I know I am getting there. From that method in the ViewController Class I am trying to perform a segue but the app crashes " And I think I figured out why " because the view did not load yet and the error I am getting is that the receiver does not have a segueWithIdentifier with that name. So I put the segue in the viewDidAppear method and the segue triggered without an error. But this won't work for me.

So the question is again Could I trigger a Segue from a NSObject Class ? 
Any thoughts ?
Regards

JZ

Comment: From a `NSObject` object? If it's a `UIViewController` one (at some level, I mean by inheritance), and if the segue exists too in the StoryBoard.

Comment: got it , thanks, that's what i thought.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your definition of "trigger".

You need to have a segue defined between two view controllers.
You need to have the source view controller currently "on screen".

At that point, you could send a notification (or some other form of message/call) from your `NSObject` to the active controller object and have it perform the segue in response.

Comment: Well, that is what I though , No the NSObject class in not in the view.

Comment: It doesn't matter where the object is as long as it can communicate with the **existing** source view controller.  (If that's what you're doing and it doesn't work, you may need to show code for anyone to help.)

Comment: Okay, thanks, I am trying something different will let you know how it turns out.

Comment: Hi again !! , i thought i would try to use storyboard ID, this is the case. In My NSObject class i made the superclass a UIViewController and used NSObject as a subclass. I am trying to use storyboard ID in a Swift Class like so and having this warning which I do not understand.                                  SpeechToTextVC *vc  = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"speechToTextID"];
            
            [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: But the warning is incompatible pointer types sending 'SpeechToTextVC ' to parameter of type 'UIViewController _Nonnull , but the Swift class is a UIViewController

Comment: I'm having trouble parsing "i made the superclass a UIViewController and used NSObject as a subclass".  Can you update your question with the actual code for what you did there?